# How to convert imported date variable to the original format in Stata?

Tags: stata

My original date variable is like this `19jun2015 16:52:04`. After importing, it looks like this: `1.77065e+12`

The storage type for the new imported variable is `str11` and display format is `%11s`

I wonder how I can restore it back to date format?

Comment: You will want to follow the instructions for converting your string variable to a SIF datetime variable following the guidance in `help datetime`, which is without a doubt the most visited documentation on my system, with the second-most-visited being Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the _Stata User's Guide_ PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 thoroughly. After that, the help datetime documentation will usually be enough to point the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William Lisowski gives excellent advice in his comment. For anyone using date-times in Stata, there is a minimal level of understanding without which confusion and outright error are unavoidable. Only study of the `help` so that your specific needs are understood can solve your difficulty.

There is a lack of detail in the question which makes precise advice difficult (imported -- from what kind of file? using which commands and/or third party programs?), except to diagnose that your dates are messed up and can only be corrected by going back to the original source.

Date strings such as `"19jun2015 16:52:04"` can be held in Stata as strings but to be useful they need to be converted to `double` numeric variables which hold the number of milliseconds since the beginning of 1960. This is a number that people cannot interpret, but Stata provides display formats so that displayed dates are intelligible.

Your example is when converted a number of the order of a trillion but if held as a string with only 6 significant figures you have, at a minimum, lost detail irretrievably.

These individual examples make my points concrete. `di` is an abbreviation for the `display` command.

`clock()` (and also `Clock()`, not shown or discussed here: see the `help`) converts string dates to milliseconds since Stata's origin. With a variable, you would use `generate double`.

```
. di %23.0f  clock("19jun2015 16:52:04", "DMY hms")
          1750351924000
```

If displayed with a specific format, you can check that Stata is interpreting your date-times correctly. There are also many small variations on the default `%tc` format to control precise display of date-time elements.

```
. di %tc  clock("19jun2015 16:52:04", "DMY hms")
19jun2015 16:52:04
```

The first example shows that even date-times which are recent dates (~2016) and in integer seconds need 10  significant figures to be accurate; the default display gives 4; somehow you have 6, but that is not enough.

```
. di  clock("19jun2015 16:52:04", "DMY hms")
1.750e+12
```

You need to import the dates again. If you import them exactly as shown, the rest can be done in Stata.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures if that phrase is unfamiliar.